# Static sprite batch?

Tags: java, libgdx

As my research goes everywhere it's said that we should only use one sprite batch per instance. But what if i set sprite batch to static in class which controls the game (calls different screens etc).

When i have tryed this its working like charm, but is that a good practice or it may result some problems in future. Then if it could be done can i also share stage and shape renderer?

note: the main reason why i am trying to go with that "static batch technique" is that java crashes when i try to dispose stage, sprite batch or shape renderer

Comment: Making this static doesn't seem like the right approach. Rather try passing around the spritebatch to share it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do it that way as well and I didn't run into any problems so far.

You need to be careful with the `SpriteBatch.begin()` and `SpriteBatch.end()` calls, since you may never know where it was started already, and where it was stopped when it is shared.

Same applies for the `Camera`/ProjectionMatrix. And also for the currently used `ShaderProgram` in case you are working with shaders.

Make sure that you are always fully aware of where you are doing what with your `SpriteBatch` otherwise you might face weird bugs one day.

`Stage` should not be shared, since it will probably serve different purposes. For different UIs it doesn't make any sense to use only one `Stage`.

`ShapeRenderer` could be shared, since it kind of works the same like `SpriteBatch`, but probably you only want to use it in a single place.

`dispose()` should actually work without any problems. You have to make sure that you dispose everything in the correct order so nothing will be left over in the end and cause exceptions.

Comment: well that is great then.

For where i use my batch there will be no problem becouse its only used once at a time. I pass batch to object which need to be rendered, so that i have everything on the same place

many thanks for the comment

Answer (score 1):

As @noone allready said it should not cause any problems, if you take care.
But i just wanted to point out another thing: In some `Screen`s (`MenuScreen`, `OptionScreen`, ...) you may use `Scene2dUi` for some UI stuff. So you will use `Stage`s, which belong to the `Screen` and are not shared. So in this case you should remember, that every `Stage` has its own `SpriteBatch` and `Camera`. So it could be, that you only need an additional `SpriteBatch` in your
`GameScreen`. If this is the case i would not make it static and have it only in the `GameScreen`.
As noone said `dispose()` should work, if you use the correct order, and so also going with more then 1 `SpriteBatch` should not cause any problems.
So i think both ways will work and are good approaches. It depends on your design and how/where you want to use the `SpriteBatche`s and `Camera`s.

Comment: No problem. Good luck with your game!