# LibGdx : Keep one spriteBatch as singleton in Game? Or one spriteBacth per Screen?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, spritebatch

In LibGdx **SpriteBatch** doc. it's mentionned that

> A SpriteBatch is a pretty heavy object so you should only ever have one in your **program**.

But i'm confused a little ! I want to know if i have to maintain one SpriteBatch in all the Game(as singleton) or have one SpriteBatch per Screen as shown in several tutorials that i find till now.

I also want to know if is a good idea to keep a SpriteBatch as singleton.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get some informations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22121694/static-sprite-batch/22149252#22149252).

In my opinion you can have 1 or even 2 `SpriteBatch`s per `Screen`. If you set another `Screen` as your current the `hide()` method is called, and there you can simply `dispose()` your `SpriteBatch`.
This means, that you have to create a new one in the `show()` method.
You can use one `SpriteBatch` for game and one for `HUD/UI` without any problems. But always make sure you call `end()` on one before calling `begin()` on the other, so that only one `SpriteBatch` is active at a time.
Of course if you don't need more then one you should not use more then one. And if you want you can also have one for the whole gmae. But be carefull with the different `ProjectionMatrix`es you may use for different screens.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I'll also check the link.